# Ultima 6 - who knows where to find the vortex cube

Tags: ultima-6

I have surrendered to Lord Draxinusim and promised to give my life as a sacrife. Since then i can talk to the Gargoyles. I learned from the Book of Rituals that i can return the codex if i put the Moonstones inside the **vortex cube** and use the Lens from the Gargoyle (and yes - also use the Lens of the human, later i learned from the seer).

[image]

### Question

how do i know where to find the vortex cube?

### Note

of course i have read (in the oh-so-many walkthroughs) that the Cyclopses in ?Stonekeep? have the cube, but i have no idea why i should search for the cube right there! **is there a hint**, why it's in Stonekeep and not in the gargoyle realm?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The caretaker in the Hall of Knowledge mentions that the cube was stolen from the gargoyles by two humans thieves and that they were heard mentioning Stonegate as they fled.

This is the relevant line:

**cham,vort,libr,huma**: "To have three rooms here:" "To keep artifacts from the Underworld in the Human Chamber, to the east." "To keep valuable books in the Librum Chamber, to the west." "And to keep the Cube and the Lens in the Vortex Chamber, to the south."

**cube**: "To regret that that item is lost, stolen by human thieves years ago." "To have heard the humans mention the name Stonegate as they fled." "To have heard them say they would sail through Lost Hope Bay." "To know nothing more about its whereabouts."

So, once again, the expected plot would probably have you look in the Hall for the Cube, find out it is no longer stored there, ask for info and get the clue to Stonegate.

Comment: ok - i definitly talk too little with the characters in the game - instead of talking i rushed to the objects and ignored the keeper of the hall of knowledge - thank you very very much!!! all makes sense now!